# Select value on next date to be calculated on current date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
ID   GroupID    oDate       oTime     oValue
1    A          2014-06-01  00:00:00  100
2    A          2014-06-01  01:00:00  200
3    A          2014-06-01  02:00:00  300
4    A          2014-06-02  00:00:00  400
5    A          2014-06-02  01:00:00  425
6    A          2014-06-02  02:00:00  475
7    B          2014-06-01  00:00:00  1000
8    B          2014-06-01  01:00:00  1500
9    B          2014-06-01  02:00:00  2000
10   B          2014-06-02  00:00:00  3000
11   B          2014-06-02  01:00:00  3100
12   A          2014-06-03  00:00:00  525
13   A          2014-06-03  01:00:00  600
14   A          2014-06-03  02:00:00  625
```

I want to have the following result:

```
GroupID   oDate         oResult
A         2014-06-01    300
A         2014-06-02    125
B         2014-06-01    2000
```

oResult is coming from:

Value on next date at 00:00:00 subtract value on selected date at 00:00:00.
For example, I want to know the Result for `2014-06-01`. Then,

```
2014-06-02 00:00:00 400 substract 2014-06-01 00:00:00 100
oResult = 400 - 100 = 300
```

How can I achieve this in SQL syntax?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain your desire output in better way, for me it is very difficult to understand.

Comment: still not clear, please explain 2nd row of your output.

Comment: @AK47, I put 3 rows on the output, what I want is... value on next date at 00:00:00 minus value on current date at 00:00:00 ...

Comment: ok, but how will you decide that which 3 rows to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a query using `Common Table Expression` as  :

```
;with CTE as
( select row_number() over ( partition by GroupID, oDate order by oTime Asc) as rownum, 
         GroupID, oDate, oValue,oTime
  from Test
)
select CTE.GroupID,CTE1.oDate, (CTE.oValue - CTE1.oValue) as oResult
from CTE
inner join CTE as CTE1 on datediff (day,CTE1.oDate, CTE.oDate) = 1  
and CTE1.rownum= CTE.rownum 
and  CTE1.GroupID= CTE.GroupID
where CTE.rownum = 1
```

[Check Demo here ...](http://rextester.com/SQBKBN95726)

Comment: Hi, the date is wrong on the result. 300 should be on 2014-06-01

Comment: maybe need to change CTE.oDate to dateadd(dd, -1, CTE.oDate) AS oDate. Please edit your answer, then I'll vote it.

Comment: Updated `CTE.oDate` to `CTE1.oDate`.. please check now.. It'll give correct results..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross apply` operator here
Please check this,

```
select a.GroupID,a.oDate, (ab.oValue - a.oValue) oResult from T as a
cross apply 
(
    select top 1 * from T  as b
    where a.oDate < b.oDate
    and oTime = '00:00:00.0000000'
    and a.ID < b.ID

)as ab
where a.ID in(1,4,7)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27a64/1)

Comment: hi, the WHERE criteria should be by oDate. Let say, I want to know the Result on '2014-06-01', then the result is 300.

Comment: ok, that means instead of a.ID in(1,4,7) you need a.oDate = 'somedate'. correct?

Comment: I just mark the correct answer. Just check it. Cheers,

Comment: Great! but just for discussion purpose, don't you think answer is a bit confusing? I would suggest you to read APPLY operators in SQL. It will help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you. Not make me confuse, but please to understand my question first then ask.